# How I can send a Ctrl + P to window if i khow a handle of this window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How I can send a Ctrl + P to window if i khow a handle of this window?

I think that i must use

```
PostMessage(hWnd...
```

Comment: Have you considered using Spy++ to monitor the messages and parameters the window recieves when you hit CTRL+P? Once you know this you send these yourself with a call to PostMessage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [ControlSpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773165%28VS.85%29.aspx) and, as Thomas Sampson says, check what messages are sent when you press Ctrl-P. After that you can use PostMessage and reproduce this behaviour. **However**, do check the state of a [WM_CHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646276%28VS.85%29.aspx) and what you need to fill in. That's a lot. This is why they created `keybd_event`, which has been superseded by [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx). But, as I noticed, this does not specify a handle to which you can send the information.

**Which leads me to the question**: are you sure you are addressing your issue the correct way? If you want the program to print, you might want to check for other ways to make the program print, for instance defining your own `WM_USER+x` message that you can handle without simulating keypresses

Answer (score 2):

Upon further investigation, the SendInput Windows API call may be what you require? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx

Comment: Note: This function is subject to UIPI. Applications are permitted to inject input only into applications that are at an equal or lesser integrity level.

Comment: but sendinput doesn't specify the HWND to where it should be sent

Answer (score 1):

It's a (old) win32 FAQ... (> 16 years)
You can see on [Professional Win32 newsgroup](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/topics?lnk=srg)
news://nntp.aioe.org/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32